# ODE give wrong result for integral operation

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, wolframalpha

I'm trying to code an algorithm that uses the ODE function, but I'm getting the wrong result for some input.
for
[image: text]
the correct answer should be:
[image: text]

like it can be seen here:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=dsolve%28x%27%28t%29%3D+1%2F%28C+-+t%29%29

but what I get is:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, Eq, Function
>>> from sympy import pprint
>>> from sympy import dsolve
>>> x = Function("x")
>>> t = symbols("t")
>>> C1 = symbols("C1")
>>> eq = Eq(x(t).diff(t) - 1/(C1-t))
>>> pprint(eq)
d            1       
──(x(t)) - ────── = 0
dt         C₁ - t    
>>> pprint(dsolve(eq))
x(t) = C₂ - log(-C₁ + t)
```

which isn't the correct answer:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=is+-log%28c-x%29+%3D+-log%28x-c%29+%3F

How can I fix the code?

Comment: If we pretend for a second that there is no problem with writing log(-1), then:   log(t - C1) = log((-1)(C1-t) = log(-1) + log(C1-t) and then the frightful log(-1) can be hidden inside C2.

Answer (score 1):

The answer returned here by `dsolve` is correct and so is the one given by Wolfram Alpha as well. There is not a unique form for the general solution of an ODE because there are different ways to define the arbitrary constants. Here the difference between `log(t - C1)` and `log(C1 - t)` is just `I*pi` which can be absorbed into the arbitrary constant `C2`. The two different forms for the general solution are both correct but would have different values for `C2` in order to satisfy the same initial conditions.

If you expected everything to be real (rather than complex) then `log(C1 - t)` will be defined only for `t < C1` and `log(t - C1)` will be defined only for `t > C1`. It isn't necessary to return different forms for `t < C1` and `t > C1` though because both general solutions given hold for all (complex) `t != C1` provided you understand that the constant `C2` is not constrained to be real.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I agree and understand what you said, but the way the result is presented is very important to me.  I've found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121121/integration-of-1-x-in-sympy but it works only if the expression inside the log is where x is the only variable, if I have one more symbolic like "log(-a+x)" it's failing but for "log(-1+x)" it works great.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in this follow up comment. Better to ask a new question. This question is answered: the result is not wrong.